# How to make multiple API calls with rate limits per user using RabbitMQ?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

In my app I am getting data on behalf of different users via one API which has a rate limit of 1 API call every 2 seconds per user.

Currently I am storing all the calls I need to make in a single message queue. I am using RabbitMQ for this.

There is currently one consumer who is taking one message at a time, doing the call, processing the result and then start with the next message.

The queue is filling up faster than this single consumer can make the API calls (1 call every 2 seconds as I don't know which user comes next and I don't want to hit API limits).

My problem is now that I don't know how to add more consumers which in theory would be possible as the queue holds jobs for different users and the API rate limit is per user so e.g. I could do 2 API calls every 2 seconds if they are from different users.

However I have no information about the messages in the queue. Could be from a single user, could be from many different users.

Only solution I see right now is to create separate queues for each user. But I have many different users (say 1,000) and would rather stay with 1 queue.

If possible I would stick with RabbitMQ as I use this for other similar tasks as well. But if I need to change my stack I would be willing to do so.

App is using the MEAN stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to maintain a state somewhere, I had a similar application and what i did was maintain state in `Redis`, before every call check if user has made request in last 2 seconds eg:

**Redis key:**

```
user:<user_id> // value is epoch time-stamp
```

update `Redis` once request is made.

**refrence:**

[redis](https://redis.io/commands)

Comment: How would you structure the queues then (one or many)? How would you set up the consumers (one or many)? New users might show up as they sign up regularly.

Comment: What I did for consumers was watch messages count in queue, according to which I spawned consumers. And if a consumer is idle for a period of time it killed itself. You can use child_processes so that one master process will manage other child process